Return largest shareholder ownership - Bloomberg
I am attempting to return the ownership percentage of the largest owner from several stocks using Bloomberg API in excel. Does anyone know of a relevant function to use?
I have found "TOP_20_HOLDERS_PUBLIC_FILINGS" that can get me the ownership of the top 20 largest shareholders, but I only want the very largest owner in each stock. Any way to only extract the largest one?
Any help would be much appreciated!
PS:As I am using a educational Bloomberg license I am not able to ask Bloomberg help directly

=TAKE(BDS("AAPL US Equity","TOP_20_HOLDERS_PUBLIC_FILINGS","ARRAY=TRUE"),1)

@DS_London Thank you so much, worked like a charm! :)
Forgot to mention in original post, but is it also possible to get this data from a specific point in time, same way as BDH works. Eg: "Get Apple's largest owner on the date 02/10/2023"
P

I had a quick look and I am not sure it is possible to get historic dates.
